# Vaadin grid context menu does not open/show

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-grid

I can't get a grid context menu to show. Vaadin 7.6.3, vaadin-context-menu 0.7.4.

```
GridContextMenu gridContextMenu = new GridContextMenu(grid);
gridContextMenu.addGridBodyContextMenuListener(e -> eventGridRowContext(e));
```

And the handler:

```
private void eventGridRowContext(GridContextMenuOpenEvent e)
{
  Job job = (Job) e.getItemId();

  if(job == null)
  {
    return;
  }

  grid.select(job);

  ContextMenu contextMenu = e.getContextMenu();
  contextMenu.removeItems();
  contextMenu.addItem("Test", e2 -> Notification.show("Test"));
  contextMenu.open(e.getX(), e.getY());
}
```

I'm getting the event. Debugger runs right through the open call, but nothing happens.

Comment: Have you recompiled your widgetset? [This article](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/using-contextmenu-with-vaadin-7-6) and [this thread](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/12420543/12420542) suggest that you need to do so in order for the add-on to work

Comment: @IanA I'm using the precompiled widgetset from vaadin (vaadin-client-compiled).

Comment: I may be completely wrong as I'm fairly new to Vaadin but I was under the impression that you couldn't use the precompiled widget set if using [addons](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/addons/addons-overview.html) that include widgets, as the addon widgetset needs to be compiled into the application widgetset

Comment: @IanA Thank you for the suggestion - I will try with a custom widgetset next.

Comment: @IanA 20 hours later... Using a custom widgetset did the trick. But OMG that was a whole other pain to set up correctly. Please convert to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a custom add-on which includes widgets then you're not able to use the precompiled widgetset as the add-on widgetset needs to be compiled into the application widgets.

The [Vaadin Addons documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/addons/addons-overview.html) states...

*"Most add-ons include widgets, client-side counterparts of the server-side components used in the Vaadin Java API, as illustrated in Role of the widget set. The widget set needs to be compiled into the application widget set."*

[This article](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/using-contextmenu-with-vaadin-7-6) and [this thread](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/12420543/12420542) suggest that you need to recompile the widgetset for the vaadin-context-menu add-on to work.